# Getting VALUE error in Excel using a sum range and criteria 1 with a single cell criteria 2

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a scenario where I have a table with some amount and some information relating to those specific amount.

I don't have a single cell with a date in it. What I am trying to do is a sumifs on the range which includes the amount and the specific data  but the sumifs also contains a criteria referencing only a single cell which has the date but I am getting the value error for the formula. If I split into two parts and create a Cell containing the the sum on the criteria and then use this single cell in the sumif instead of the range it works

But how can I get this to work as one formula?

My formula looks something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,"YES",A1,A2)
```

where the `B` range are the amounts, the `C` range are the criteria to match against and the two `A` cells are both dates I want to match up.

Answer (score -1):

The ranges used in SUMIFS have to be symmetrical.  They can be different columns but must contain the same number of cells.  I don't think that `SUMIFS` is going to be able to handle the mix of ranges and individual cells that you are looking to do.  One workaround would be to put the criterion from `A2` into `D1`.  The formula would look something like this:
`=SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,"YES",A2:A5,"CriterionfromA1",D2:D5,"CriterionfromD1")`